# Python row index of deleted row

Tags: python, numpy

I'm deleting rows from an array like this-

```
Data_deleted_row=Data_v_co[numpy.all(Data_v_co < 0, axis=0)]
```

How can I get the indexes of the deleted rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how numpy.all() deletes the row. 
Either case, just before deleting you have to find such indices.

```
deleted_rows= numpy.where(Data_v_co > 0)
Data_deleted_row=Data_v_co[numpy.all(Data_v_co < 0, axis=0)]
```

I tried something similar and this is what I got

```
In [35]: a = np.random.randint(-5,1, [5,6]);
Out[36]: 
array([[-2, -3, -4, -4, -2, -2],
       [-2, -4, -4,  0, -5, -2],
       [-5,  0, -1, -2, -2, -1],
       [-3, -1,  0, -5, -3, -2],
       [-1, -5,  0, -4, -5, -5]])

In [37]: b = np.all(a < 0, axis=0)

In [38]: b
Out[38]: array([ True, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [39]: deleted_indices = np.where(b == False)

In [40]: deleted_indices
Out[40]: (array([1, 2, 3]),)

In [41]: c = a[:,b]

In [42]: c
Out[42]: 
array([[-2, -2, -2],
       [-2, -5, -2],
       [-5, -2, -1],
       [-3, -3, -2],
       [-1, -5, -5]])
```

Comment: I will have to change `axis=1` to get the rows. Thanks a bunch.